# How to define Show for heterogenous lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gadt

I'm researching into what Haskell can offer on it's way to dependent types by reading `Thinking with types`.

Here's an heteregenous list defined as GADT.

```hs
data HList (ts :: [Type]) where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    (:#) :: t -> HList ts -> HList (t ': ts)

infixr 5 :#

instance Eq (HList '[]) where
    HNil == HNil = True

instance (Eq t, Eq (HList ts)) => Eq (HList (t ': ts)) where
    (a :# as) == (b :# bs) = a == b && as == bs


instance Ord (HList '[]) where
    compare HNil HNil = EQ

instance (Ord t, Ord (HList ts)) => Ord (HList (t ': ts)) where
    compare (a :# as) (b :# bs) = case compare a b of
                                    EQ -> compare as bs
                                    x -> x

instance Show (HList '[]) where
    show HNil = "[]"

instance (Show t, Show (HList ts)) => Show (HList (t ': ts)) where
    show xs = "[" ++ (show' xs "") ++ "]"
        where
            show' (y :# ys) prefix = prefix ++ (show y) ++ rest
                where rest = case  of
                               HNil -> ""
                               _ -> show' ys ", "
```

Here's the error I get.

```
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: ts2 ~ t1 : ts2
      Expected type: HList ts2 -> [Char] -> [Char]
        Actual type: HList ts1 -> p -> p1
    • In the expression: show' ys ", "
      In a case alternative: _ -> show' ys ", "
      In the expression:
        case ys of
          HNil -> ""
          _ -> show' ys ", "
    • Relevant bindings include
        ys :: HList ts2 (bound at src/Lib.hs:43:25)
        y :: t1 (bound at src/Lib.hs:43:20)
   |
46 |                                _ -> show' ys ", "
```

I read the HList source code and what they do is what I think is an ugly hack where they pattern match on a string that is returned from `show ys` and if it's equal to `[]` then stop the recursion basically, which I consider to be a hack.

Comment: you have `case  of
                               HNil -> "" ;
                               ys -> show' ys ", "`. is this supposed to be `case ys of
                               HNil -> "" ;
                               ys -> show' ys ", "`?

Comment: @WillNess I've changed the code. It suppose to mean the thing that is shown in error.

Comment: `case *what* of HNil -> ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier if you define your own custom class, and recurse on that one. This is because we can't pass the `prefix` argument to the standard `show` method, but this is no longer an issue in a custom class.

```
class HShow ts where
    hshow :: HList ts -> String -> String

instance HShow '[] where
    hshow HNil _ = ""

instance (Show t, HShow ts) => HShow (t ': ts) where
    hshow (y :# ys) p = p ++ show y ++ hshow ys ", "
```

After that, we can add the brackets and obtain the standard `Show` class instance:

```
instance HShow ts => Show (HList ts) where
    show xs = "[" ++ hshow xs "" ++ "]"

test :: HList '[ Int, Char, Bool ]
test = 42 :# 'a' :# True :# HNil

-- > test
-- [42, 'a', True]
```

---

An alternative based on type families. Not particularly simpler.

```
type family All (c :: a -> Constraint) (xs :: [a]) :: Constraint where
  All c '[] = ()
  All c (x ': xs) = (c x, All c xs)

hshow :: All Show ts => HList ts -> String
hshow HNil        = ""
hshow (x :# HNil) = show x
hshow (x :# xs  ) = show x ++ ", " ++ hshow xs

instance All Show ts => Show (HList ts) where
  show xs = "[" ++ hshow xs ++ "]"
```

Comment: That option came into my mind, but I hoped that there is a better solution. But it's actually not that bad...

Comment: @user1685095 You could try using a type family to define (pseudocode) the constraint `AllShow '[t1,t2,...] = (Show t1, Show t2, ...)` and then exploit that. It seems longer to write, though.

Comment: @user1685095 Added the alternative, even if we do not gain much with it.